# Angular Material - select, null option

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to add an option to a select that would unselect, and I would like to have the form item reset to it's default and not "-- NONE --".

```
<md-select ng-model="topping">
  <md-option ng-value=""> -- NONE -- </md-option>
  ...
</md-select>
```

Update

I was able to solve by watching and deleting the value, but this seems like it should be avoidable.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/dylanlawrence/pen/KdOaxq)

Answer (score 0):

An approach I have used recently is to add a clear button next to the input that becomes visible when a value has been selected and hides when the model value is cleared (which clicking the button does)

This has worked well for me and is intuitive for the user and can be used for other inputs like text and date pickers

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1:**
    since `ng-click` will be fired before the the option is assigned to `ng-model`, use `ng-change` as shown below

**HTML:**

```
<md-select ng-change="clear()" ng-model="topping>
    <md-option ng-value="none"> -- NONE -- </md-option>
     ...
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.clear=function(){
     if($scope.topping=="none")
        $scope.topping=null;
}
```

**UPDATE 1 END**

You could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<md-option ng-click="clear()">--NONE--</md-option>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.clear=function(){
     $scope.topping=null;
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work: after executing the clear function, the ng-model value for md-select is set back to the content specified by md-option (e.g. --none-- in this case)

Comment: @gru try `ng-change` on `md-select` instead of `ng-click` on the specific option. `ng-change` will be fired after the value has been assigned to the `ng-model`. Check if the selected value is none and then set the model to none

Comment: I found way easier to add a clear button aside my select that would set the model to undefined.